# What triggers Dark Sora

Tags: kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

When I go to changes forms, sometimes Dark Sora appears instead of the form I wanted. It's annoying as if I had 5 Drives stored and I used Master which only takes 4 Dark Sora will consume all Drives so I'm back to 0, it's also a pain when I am trying to grind levels for my forms and Dark Sora appears wasting the opportunity I had.

So I am wondering what triggers Dark Sora.

NOTE: I ask for Kingdom Hearts 2 for 2.5 HD Remix as I am unsure if the conditions have changed in Final Mix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anti-Form is a bit of a pain, especially while trying to power level. Unfortunately, it is triggered pseudo-randomly based on a counter (which you can't view).

The counter will increment by 1 when you use any form except Final or Anti, except if your partner has fainted. If Anti-form triggers, the counter goes down by 4, and if you use Final form it goes down by 10. If you obtain a new form (other than final), it resets the counter to 0. Mission battles, boss fights, and the final battle all increase your chance of getting anti-form, where as you can't get it against Pete, Hades, or Barbossa or while fighting with people not in your party.

The chance of getting it based on the counter is:

1. 0 -> 0%
2. 1-4 -> 10%
3. 5-9 -> 25%
4. 10+ -> 40%

[Source and a lot more info](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Anti_Form#Mechanics)